# How to catch a form submit action in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

I have a form that the user can submit using the two following buttons:

```
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="delete" id="deletebutton" class="pure-button">
<input type='submit' id="submitbutton" name="btnSubmit" value="save" class="pure-button pure-button-primary">
```

I have an `submit` event listener that loads a certain function I need to process the form (the form has id `#submitform`):

```
document.querySelector('#submitform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some code goes here
});
```

However, this code only reacts when `#submitbutton` is clicked. When `#deletebutton` is clicked the form submits as usual.

How do I avoid that and have *another* function listening to whether `#deletebutton` is clicked?

Thank you!

Comment: If both buttons are within the form, that should work just fine

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/od0mbpm8/

Comment: Note that the event listener isn't properly closed

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you simply try like below

```
 $("#submitform").submit(function(event){
    var isValid = true;

    // do all your validation if need here

    if (!isValid) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Make sure **both the buttons inside the form closing tag**
and your event listener was not properly closed

```
 document.querySelector('#submitform').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I would add another listenter for the delete button.

```
document.querySelector('#deletebutton').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // Some code goes here
    // commonFunct() { ... }
}
```

If both buttons will perform common code/action you can call a common function so you don't have to repeat yourself.